# Insert multiple data in child table in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, object-object-mapping

## Background

I have two tables `Actions` and `ActionsDetails`.

Actions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actions]
(
    [ActionId] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DeviceId] [NVARCHAR](125) NOT NULL,
    [TenantId] [INT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ActionId]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ActionId] ASC)
        WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

ActionsDetails:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActionsDetails]
(
    [ActionsDetailsId] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActionId] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [ActionName] [NVARCHAR](125) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [NVARCHAR](800) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ActionsDetailsId]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ActionsDetailsId] ASC)
        WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ActionsDetails] WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ActionsDetails_ActionsId]
        FOREIGN KEY([ActionId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Actions] ([ActionId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ActionsDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ActionsDetails_ActionsId]
GO
```

What I am trying to do is to insert a row of data in `Actions` and then capture `ActionId` for the inserted record, and then insert multiple values for that `ActionId` in `ActionsDetails` table. Very simple case of inserting into parent-child table using EF Core, just that child table can have multiple records for a parent row.

This is the piece of code which does that in `ActionsAppService` class:

```
public async Task CreateActions(CreateActionDto input)
{
    Actions actions = new Actions();
    ActionsDetails actionsdetails = new ActionsDetails();

    MapToEntity(input, actions);

    // Insert into Actions and return last generated ActionId

    long actionid = await _actionmanager.CreateActionsAsync(actions);

    // looping here since child table can have multiple record to be
    // inserted

    foreach (var actionname in input.ActionDetails)
    {
        // TODO: This can go to a mapping method as well
        actionsdetails.ActionName = actionname.ActionName;
        actionsdetails.Description = actionname.Description;
        actionsdetails.ActionId = actionid;

        // Inserting details into ActionsDetails table for the
        // corresponding ActionId

        await _actionmanager.CreateActionsDetailsAsync(actionsdetails);
    }
}
```

Data mapping between input DTO and entity:

```
private void MapToEntity(CreateActionDto actionsdto, Actions actions)
{
    actions.DeviceId = actionsdto.DeviceId;
    actions.TenantId = (int)(AbpSession.TenantId);
}
```

In `ActionManager` class:

```
public async Task<long> CreateActionsAsync(Actions input)
{
    return await _actionsRepository.InsertAndGetIdAsync(input);
}

public async Task CreateActionsDetailsAsync(ActionsDetails input)
{
    await _actionsdetailsRepository.InsertAsync(input);
}
```

## Question

The issue that I am seeing is that `ActionDetails` list only contains last value of collection which is inserted. For example, if I pass this value:

```
{
  "deviceId": "zainnewdevice",
  "actionDetails": [
    {
      "actionId": 0,
      "actionName": "switchtube1",
      "description": "this would swtich on Tube1"
    },
    {
      "actionId": 0,
      "actionName": "switchtube2",
      "description": "This would switch on Tube2"
    }
  ]
}
```

The last value of collection, i.e. `"switchtube2"` and `"This would switch on Tube2"`, is inserted in `ActionDetails` table.

Perhaps my way of getting things done is all wrong, or might be just my lack of understanding of Entity Framework and how it works, but I got a sense that the `actionsdetails` object needs to be added in context before calling the `CreateActionsDetailsAsync` in `ActionManager`. I couldn't figure out how to do it since all context is set in `DbContext` class.

Also, I was thinking maybe adding `actionsdetails` to a List and then passing that List object to `CreateActionsDetailsAsync` in `ActionManager` class would help. Perhaps I can loop through the list object there and call `await _actionsdetailsRepository.InsertAsync(input)` in a loop, but that strategy also failed.

DTO:

```
public class CreateActionDto
{
    [Required]
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ActionsDetailsDto> ActionDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Entities:

```
public class Actions : Entity<long>, IMustHaveTenant
{
    [Column("ActionId")]
    [Key]
    public override long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ActionsDetails> ActionsDetails { get; set; }

    public Actions()
    {
        ActionsDetails = new List<ActionsDetails>();
    }
}

public class ActionsDetails : Entity<long>
{
    [ForeignKey("ActionId")]
    public virtual Actions Actions { get; set; }

    [Column("ActionsDetailsId")]
    [Key]
    public override long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long ActionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ActionName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

All rows in collection should appear in `ActionsDetails` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explicit mapping

> The issue what I am seeing is that ActionDetails list only last value of collection which is inserted.

This is because you are mapping every DTO to the same entity.

```cs
// ActionsDetails actionsdetails = new ActionsDetails(); // Move this...

foreach (var actionname in input.ActionDetails)
{
    ActionsDetails actionsdetails = new ActionsDetails(); // ...here

    actionsdetails.ActionName = actionname.ActionName;
    actionsdetails.Description = actionname.Description;
    actionsdetails.ActionId = actionid;

    await _actionmanager.CreateActionsDetailsAsync(actionsdetails);
}
```

Related: [MapTo() inside of LINQ returning multiple iterations of same data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55145922/8601760)

## AutoMapper

Another way is to leverage on ABP's [Object To Object Mapping](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Object-To-Object-Mapping).

Configuration:

```cs
[AutoMapTo(typeof(Actions))] // Add this
public class CreateActionDto
{
    [Required]
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }       

 // public ICollection<ActionsDetailsDto> ActionDetails { get; set; } // Rename this
    public ICollection<ActionsDetailsDto> ActionsDetails { get; set; }
}

[AutoMapTo(typeof(ActionsDetails))] // Add this
public class ActionsDetailsDto
{
    // ...
}
```

Usage:

```cs
public async Task CreateActions(CreateActionDto input)
{
    Actions actions = new Actions();

    MapToEntity(input, actions);

    long actionId = await _actionmanager.CreateActionsAsync(actions);
}

private void MapToEntity(CreateActionDto actionsdto, Actions actions)
{
    _objectMapper.Map(actionsdto, actions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Moving ActionsDetails  inside foreach helped.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a parent child relation over Id of which EF is aware of, you do not have to set the Id. Following code should work:

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    var action= new Action();
    MapToEntity(input, action);// I asume your details are also included in the input
    context.Actions.Add(action);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to insert the `Action` and the `ActionDetails` separately. EF will take care of the insert, just pass the full entity to the insert method:

```
public async Task CreateActions(CreateActionDto input)
{
    Actions actions = new Actions();            
    ActionsDetails actionsdetails = new ActionsDetails();

    // Do your mapping
    MapToEntity(input, actions);

    // Add the details
    foreach (var actionname in input.ActionDetails)
    {
        actionsdetails.ActionName = actionname.ActionName;
        actionsdetails.Description = actionname.Description;

        // Add it to the collection
        actions.ActionsDetails.Add(actionsdetails);
    }

    // Save
    await _actionmanager.CreateActionsAsync(actions);        
}
```

The best way to avoid problems created by two separate insert statements is to wrap everything in a transaction and because you're using EF that's the default mechanism for how it works.

Comment: Thanks Cristian. I tried the code and as you and other members here guided me EF took care of Id part without me specifying it explicitly but for some reasons unknown to me it is inserting the last row. The values are passed though https://imgur.com/PPyXdsm   and  https://imgur.com/ybbJvfh.

Answer (score -2):

its kind of strange to see a repository pattern with entity framework (since ef-core is already a repository) other than that i can't see anything wrong with the code (not sure what your repository methods are doing) what you could try is

1. remove the

   public Actions()
       {
           ActionsDetails = new List();
       }

from your actions entity, since it is not needed

2. is your

   long actionid= await _actionmanager.CreateActionsAsync(actions);

saving to the database? if it does, thats alot of lost performance, since you can just return the entity (without saving) and then applying it to your Actionsdetails:

```
actionsdetails.Action = action;
```

is your `await _actionmanager.CreateActionsDetailsAsync(actionsdetails);` also already saving to the database? i don't see why you shouldn't create the objects in the foreach and then save them as a list to the database (also gives a better way to try debugging, and generally, just try to save to the database only once)

hope this helps you in any way to find your problem since it is hard to locate it without the full methods (your repository, again ef-core is already a repository)

so just try to do the following: create the actions, create the actiondetails with the reference set to the actions and after that just save everything